# How else can I format the data? swift parse json - The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: json, swift

The JSON data is

```
[
{"id":0,"temperature":77,"humidity":0.22,"timeCaptured":"2020-09-25T19:33:27.9733333"},
{"id":0,"temperature":77,"humidity":0.22,"timeCaptured":"2020-09-25T20:38:53.3"},
{"id":0,"temperature":85,"humidity":0.25,"timeCaptured":"2020-09-25T20:38:53.3"},
{"id":0,"temperature":88,"humidity":0.22,"timeCaptured":"2020-09-28T15:30:00"},
 // ...
]
```

My structs look like this

```
struct TemperatureDataModel: Codable{
    let id:              Int?
    let temperature:     Double?
    let humidty:         Double?
    let timeCaptured:    String?
}
```

My function looks like this

```
func getTemperData(){
    //Create the URLs
    let temperatureDataUrl = URL(string: "https://weatherstationapi.azurewebsites.net/api/TemperatureSensor/GetData")
    // let WindDataUrl = URL(string: "https://weatherstationapi.azurewebsites.net/api/WindData/GetAllData")
    guard let requestURLTemp = temperatureDataUrl else { fatalError() }
    //Create URL request
    var request = URLRequest(url: requestURLTemp)
    //Specifiy HTTP Method to use
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("Bearer         eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiaWxpci50YWlyaUB0dHUuZWR1IiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMueG1sc29hcC5vcmcvd3MvMjAwNS8wNS9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvbmFtZWlkZW50aWZpZXIiOiI4MjEzYzhhMy1iODgxLTQ4NmUtOGUyMC1mZmNlMDlmNGY0ZjgiLCJuYmYiOiIxNjAyNTI2NDI1IiwiZXhwIjoiMTYwNTExODQyNSJ9.t1qnYyXLpRRJ3YQfhgLrylBqL_pdKOnKVMgOfG9IuVc", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    //Send HTTP Request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        print(data)
        //Use parseJSON to convert data
        let TemperatureData = parseJSON(data: data)
        // for singleValue in TemperatureData {
        //     print(singleValue.temperautre)
        // }
        //read list
        guard let TemperatureDataModel = TemperatureData else {return}
        print("Temperature is : \(TemperatureDataModel.temperature)")
    
        // Check if error took place
        if let error = error {
            print("Error took place \(error)")
            return
        }
        //Read HTTP Response Status Code
        // if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        //    print("Response data string:\n \(dataString)")
        // }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

and then my JSON decoder function looks like this

```
func parseJSON(data: Data) -> TemperatureDataModel? {    
    var returnValue: TemperatureDataModel?
    do {
        let returnValue = try JSONDecoder().decode([TemperatureDataModel].self, from: data)
    } catch {
        print("Error took place \(error).")
    }
    return returnValue
}
```

I've looked at 6+ stack overflow posts now and still cannot figure It out. Ive tried putting my model in [] for an array, moving where the function is called, changing the jsondecoder function and more and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to give a format to the date before you parse the data

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

Answer (score 0):

Your issue there is that you are creating another `returnValue` that is not being returned. You need also change the return type to `[TemperatureDataModel]`

```
func parseJSON(data: Data) -> [TemperatureDataModel]? {
    do {
        return try JSONDecoder().decode([TemperatureDataModel].self, from: data)
    } catch {
        print("Error took place \(error).")
        return nil
    }
}
```